# image_field não esta aparecendo no template no django

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando colocar uma img do banco de dados usando o {{file.url}}, mas não aparece nada na pagina. Poderiam me dizer o que estou fazendo errado?

**model:**

```
class Noticia(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True )
```

**url:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
#views
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings:**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

settings-context_processors:

```
'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ]
```

**template:**

```
{%for noti in noticia%}
<h1 id="cor">{{noti.titulo}}</h1>
<img src="{{noti.imagem.url}}">
{%endfor%}
```

**view:**

```
def news(request, pk):
    notic = Noticia.objects.filter(id=pk).values()
    
    nova_news = {
        'noticia': notic
    }

    return render(request, 'pags/noticia.html', nova_news)
```

Eu tentei seguir a documentação do django, as imagens vão para a pasta, mas não aparecem no template, por favor me ajudem

Comment: como está o seu `views.py`?

Comment: oi, eu acabei de adc a view no post, poderia dar uma olhada pfv?

Comment: eu acabei de dar uma olhada, parece ser um erro de configuração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao que tudo indica isso é um erro de configuração. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) diz o seguinte:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Porém em sua configuração o URL's está utilizando o `STATIC_URL` e `STATIC_ROOT` .

Lembrando que as configurações acima são apenas utilizadas e recomendadas para o modo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Obgd pela resposta, realmente tava incorreto, depois que eu troquei, ainda não tava pegando, mas descobri q é porque eu usei o filter la na view. obrigado ein